# useMemo behaviour across components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my component, I'm using [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to run and cache a somewhat expensive query to the browser runtime. So far, it has cut back dramatically on the time required for subsequent renders.

However, the actual first render is still a problem. I'm rendering thousands of instances of my component at once, and it seems that the expensive query gets repeated unnecessarily. The same query result could be used for a lot of those instances, as I'm using only two or three unique inputs for the query at once. The query could be considered pure, as it consistently returns the same result for the same inputs.

I'm left wishing that the memoized return value was available to other instances of the same component, but the profiling data suggests that it is not.

**Is there a clean and sustainable way to ensure that a memoized result is shared across all calls to the same function, regardless of the originating component instance?**

Comment: Maybe you could move these heavy calculations up to the parent component and pass it down to your thousand child components as props?

Comment: @Tholle That's something I'd rather not do, because there can be multiple different parent components. The thousands are not direct children of the same parent.

Answer (score 12):

The state that is maintained by React hooks is specific to component instance where they are called.

In order for `useMemo` or `useCallback` to have a common state for multiple component instances, they should occur in nearest common parent and be provided with context API to deeply nested children if needed.

In case it should behave in a different way, general-purpose memoization utility should be used, like [Lodash `memoize`](https://lodash.com/docs/#memoize):

```
const expensiveFn = () => ...;

const memoizedExpensiveFn = _.memoize(expensiveFn);
```

It also allows to have control over cache storage:

```
memoizedExpensiveFn.Cache = ES6MapWithExpiration;
```